# What should I know about networking before I use rsync?

Tags: ssh, rsync, localhost

My friend just told me about rsync, and I tried to use it in command line. I was able to copy a file from one place to another on my own computer, but when I tried to 'rsync' a file to another computer on the same wifi, it wouldn't let me.

It said something like "that computer denied you. ssh problems" I can't remember exactly. But ssh is still a difficult concept for me. I wouldn't know where to put the keys or how to see if there is a problem with them. I don't know hardly anything about wifi or networking in general.

**What I *do* know about networking:**
I've had to use PuTTY when I used to have a Windows. And I've connected to an AWS RDB instance from MySQL Workbench. I've had to learn about IP addresses and ports. I have a basic understanding of HTTP and URLs. I've used ssh keygen a few times.

But I don't know where to start when it comes to networking in general. What should I know / which tools should I be familiar with before I use rsync?

***EDIT** The reason I ask: I could look up the error, and read the documentation on rsync, and probably make it work. But if I go about it that way, I will probably run into problems every time I try to use rsync. Then, I could learn problem by problem like I have with other tools. But I think I can avoid that style of learning and hopefully save some time if I just learn the right things about networking before I try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know:

- to access remote systems `rsync` uses SSH protocol by default
- SSH protocol implementations (by default) verify the identify of both: the server and the client

  - to verify server, client uses [Trust On First Use](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) trust model and by default it remembers the servers it connected to in `-/.ssh/known_hosts` file
  - if you replace the server with another one (at the same name or IP address), the client will complain and require you to manually remove the entry from the `-/.ssh/known_hosts` file
- client can be authenticated using a password-based or key-based authentication

  - password-based authentication is [considered less secure](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/69407/86652) (although it is not inherently insecure)
  - for key-based authentication you use two keys: public and private (you generate them with [`ssh-keygen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-keygen) command usually on the client)
  - you add the public key (contents of the `-/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` fileon the client) to the `-/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the account home directory on the server (again by default) or you can use [`ssh-copy-id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id) command to do it for you
  - you store the private key usually in `-/.ssh/id_rsa` on the client
  - you should consider protecting the private key with a passphrase (you can further configure GPG keychain to remember the passphrase for you for a specified time)
- server SSH daemon configuration is stored in [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](http://man.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man5/sshd_config.5)
- SSH client configuration can be stored in `~/.ssh/config`
- majority of problems with SSH are related to authentication, if you encounter any, you should try connecting to the remote machine with `ssh` command and add `-vvv` option to display detailed messages, try to unstated the reason, and include the results in questions on StackExchange or AskUbuntu, if you cannot identify the problem yourself
- all above describes the defaults or typical scenario, `rsync` might be configured to use different transport protocol or used directly over TCP with `rsync://` addresses; SSH can be configured with a myriad of settings influencing the operations